# Qooxdoo : parent child selectbox

Tags: qooxdoo

I am new at Qooxdoo framework (using 4.1)

I need to create two selectBoxs `s1, s2`.

`s2` should reload based on the selection of the  `s1`.

How I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you like to use data binding or not. I would suggest to use data binding because it brings in a lot of comfort. Here is a simple sample on how to connect two virtual select boxes:

```
var s1 = new qx.ui.form.VirtualSelectBox();
this.getRoot().add(s1);

var s2 = new qx.ui.form.VirtualSelectBox();
this.getRoot().add(s2, {top: 30});

var data1 = new qx.data.Array(["a", "b", "c"]);
s1.setModel(data1);


s1.getSelection().addListener("change", function() {
  var oldModel = s2.getModel();
  if (oldModel) {
    oldModel.dispose();
  }
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    data.push(s1.getSelection().getItem(0) + " " + i);
  }
  var data2 = new qx.data.Array(data);
  s2.setModel(data2);
});
```

You can test that code online using the playground: http://tinyurl.com/posmccf